# Equity Stock Portfolio Management Website using Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to built a website for stock portfolio management. In that case, I need to take input of certain fields like stock code, buy value and quantity from the user. But I want to display more fields like today's value, today's change etc etc in the portfolio. Do I need to define them in models? As i don't need user input in that but it uses the user input for doing calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking about doing something similar this morning and came across this post.  Have you looked at [Pyfolio](https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio) as a library.  Amay22 has also got a [Django portfolio](https://github.com/Amay22/PyFolio) platform.  This would need to be adapted as it uses a Yahoo stock price api which I think is [no longer running](http://www.financial-hacker.com/bye-yahoo-and-thank-you-for-the-fish/).  There is a newer price feed which is [alphavantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/)